# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable #

Tags: python

I get to the point where it makes one sphere, then I get that error. I have no clue what to do. The whole point of this code is to make the slider work

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial
import os
import random as rand

class gridTestUI():
    def __init__(self, winName="gridTest"):
        #Attributes of the class
        self.winTitle = "create a window with a grid layout"
        #This is the name of the window
        self.winName = winName
        self.numSpheres = 3
        self.getSpheres = []
        self.makeSpheres()
        self.createUI()
        self.movePlacement = []#my change
    def createUI(self):
        #Test to see if the window exists
        if cmds.window(self.winName, exists=True):
            #delete the window
            cmds.deleteUI(self.winName)
        #create a new window
        cmds.window(self.winName, title=self.winTitle)

        cmds.scrollLayout( 'scrollLayout' )
        cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
        cmds.frameLayout( label='Buttons', borderStyle='in' )
        self.mainGrid = cmds.gridLayout( numberOfColumns=self.numSpheres, cellWidthHeight=(200, 200) )        
        for sphereName in self.getSpheres:
            cmds.button(l=sphereName,command=partial(self.selectSphere, sphereName))
        #This command allow you to create a button
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        cmds.frameLayout( label='Sliders', borderStyle='etchedIn' )
        cmds.columnLayout()
        self.moveSlider = cmds.floatSliderGrp( label='Move Sphere', field=True, minValue=-10.0, maxValue=10.0, value=0 )
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        cmds.showWindow( self.winName )
        #cmds.window(self.winName, edit=True, widthHeight=[450,300])


    def selectSphere(self,args=None,arg=None):
        cmds.select(args)

    def makeSpheres(self):
            for j in range(self.numSpheres):
                self.movePlacement = [0,2,3,6,8,10,12,14,16]
                self.getSpheres.append(cmds.polySphere()[0] 
                cmds.move(movePlacement[j],rand(0,9)*moveSlider,movePlacement[j])
    myGrid = gridTestUI()
```

I think the error is coming up here. Maya seems to go through the rest of the code just fine.

Comment: show us the full error msg

Comment: # Error: 'module' object is not callable
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 60, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 19, in __init__
#   File "<maya console>", line 57, in makeSpheres
# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable #

Comment: To help people help you try to give a full, executable example complete with imports [MCVE].

Comment: I haven't seen anyone else use this method. There is no other executable example that is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the error message you posted:

```
# Error: 'module' object is not callable
# Traceback (most recent call last): 
# File "<maya console>", line 60, in <module> 
# File "<maya console>", line 19, in init 
# File "<maya console>", line 57, in makeSpheres 
# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The error is in `makeSpheres`, so look at that method:

```
def makeSpheres(self):
    for j in range(self.numSpheres):
        self.movePlacement = [0,2,3,6,8,10,12,14,16]
        self.getSpheres.append(cmds.polySphere()[0] 
        cmds.move(movePlacement[j], rand(0, 9) * moveSlider, movePlacement[j])
```

There it is: `rand(0, 9)`. `rand` is how you imported the `random` module, which, as the error message says, is not callable. What you want to call is the `random` module's `randint` method instead.

Change the method to:

```
def makeSpheres(self):
    for j in range(self.numSpheres):
        self.movePlacement = [0,2,3,6,8,10,12,14,16]
        self.getSpheres.append(cmds.polySphere()[0] 
        cmds.move(
            movePlacement[j],
            rand.randint(0, 9) * moveSlider,
            movePlacement[j])
```

And things should work (or you should get a different error if there's a different issue with your code).